# Show a certain Galois group is abelian

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $F$ be a field such that char($F$) does not divide $n$, where $\alpha$ is an element of an extension field of $F$ such that $\alpha^n \in F$, and suppose also that GCD($n$, $[F(\alpha) : F]$) = 1. Then if $\zeta$ is a primitive $n$th root of unity, it follows that $F(\alpha, \zeta)$ is Galois over $F$, since it is the splitting field of the separable polynomial $x^n - \alpha^n$ over $F$.

Now I want to try showing that the Galois group of $F(\alpha, \zeta)$ over $F$ is abelian, but I'm not sure of the best way to proceed. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: Does this not follow from the answer to one of your previous questions, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2175362/showing-that-a-certain-field-extension-is-galois ? There, you showed that $F(\alpha) = F(\zeta)$. This implies that $F(\alpha, \zeta) = F(\zeta)$. All the automorphisms in $Gal(F(\zeta):F)$ are of the form $\zeta \mapsto \zeta^e$ where $gcd(e,n) = 1$, so $Gal(F(\zeta):F)$ is abelian...

Comment: Do you specifically want clarification about the concept of the field norm, which was used in the previous answer?

Comment: Oh yes, you're absolutely right. Thanks!

Comment: So is the "field norm" the thing you wanted clarification about?

Comment: I understand the field norm now, but your first comment helped me to consolidate the answer to my previous question, with my current question. :)

Comment: Awesome - I'm glad it's sorted.